# Skew-symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, bilinear-form, symplectic-geometry

If we do symplectic linear algebra on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then 
what does $$\omega(v,w) \neq 0$$ or $$\omega(v,w) = 0$$ actually tell us about the vectors $v,w$? ($\omega$ is the skew-symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form)
Afais, the first property tells us that they are linearly independent.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I believe you are correct about the first property. As for the implications of the second I am not sure.